# Footer is in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a layout where the footer is always at the end.
However, the HTML body should have a div fixed to the left and right split another with the remaining size.

Until then I have no problem ...
But when the right div has many lines of HTML not generally continues until the end, and the footer is in the middle of the screen.

When # main is with position: relative; happens the error, but if you take it, the speakers do not work the way I need.

I've tried everything and could not fix.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WzE3g/

```
#principal 
{
    width:100%; 
    float : left;   
    word-wrap: break-word;    
    /*display: block;*/
    position:relative;
    /*position:inherit;*/
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **position:fixed;** instead of absolute in **#rodape** element. This way it will be always at the the end.

Comment: That works, but you'll also need to build in some padding so that the contents of the body don't slide behind it.

Comment: Adjust as you said, but the problem is that the # main is fixed size, it does not follow the pattern of other texts.

Adjusted for "Column2" has the correct height
http://jsfiddle.net/WzE3g/1/

Comment: @marlon.tiedt adding **padding-bottom:30px** to .coluna2 DIV will do it.

Comment: @marlon.tiedt Look at this: **http://jsfiddle.net/WzE3g/4/**. Note the last line (FINAL TEXT).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the sticky footer...
Here is an [example](http://www.martinbean.co.uk/bootstrap/sticky-footer/) with the explanation